# How can I reference tables from multiple databases within the same server in a common table expression (CTE)?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a SQL Server 2014 Express with multiple databases. One of them has general tables with information common to the remaining databases (let's call this database `UniversalData`).

The other databases have information that is pertinent to a specific site (let's call one of these databases `Site01Data`). The universal data may change and I don't want to replicate it regularly to the other site-specific databases, so I want to include the `UniversalData` table in some queries, some of which involve CTEs.

What I am trying to accomplish:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
     SELECT * 
     FROM UniversalData.dbo.someTable
),
CTE2 AS 
(
     SELECT * 
     FROM Site01Data.dbo.anotherTable
), 
CTE3 AS
(
     SELECT CTE1.field1, CTE2.field2 
     FROM CTE1 
     JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.idx = CTE2.idx
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE3;
```

This doesn't generate an error, but I seem to get no data from the CTE1 in my final query (null result set). Intuitively, does this mean it is saving a temp table in the `UniversalData` database that is not accessible from the `Site01Data` database?

How can I use a CTE with tables from different databases on the same server?

Comment: There should be no issues at all joining tables across multiple databases as long as they are all on the same instance.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the reply. Let me try the query again. I must have some other problem if I am not getting results, given that you say it should work with no issues.  I guess I delete the question if it works?

Comment: Hopefully it works for you or you find out why it isn't working as expected. Either way, I see no reason to delete anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this..

You could read the tables in one database into a temp table on the second database and then join to it.. or join both of them on the fly.

but first.. refrain from doing select *.. specify the columns

You could go

```
select t1.column1,t2.column2

from UniversalData.dbo.someTable t1

inner join Site01Data.dbo.anotherTable t2
 on t2.ida = t2.idx
```

and so onn.. it depends on which way you want to specify the join and what sort of join you want to choose..

This assumes that both the data bases are on the same instance.. else you will need linked servers

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harry. I see that you are saying it should work fine as well. I am retesting to see if I don't have a different problem with my query. I had chosen to use a CTE because I reused a lot of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Specify servername.site1data.dbo.table etc and use linked servers if appropriate across different servernames